# Is it possible to use AppsKey or other keys as modifier

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, autohotkey, modifier-keys

Is it possible to use <kbd>AppsKey</kbd> (context menu key) or other keys as modifier using AutoHotKey program?

Comment: See this [discussion](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=53971) may be its what you are looking for. As you have not told what have you tried yet.

Comment: Glad to help you. So should I post that as an answer?

Comment: @avirk Actually I found answer in the documentation page that your link refers to, so it is better that you make an answer from that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about AHK scripting so if there anything wrong anyone can fix it and this is from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=53971).

```
;Try out new hotkey mappings (Ctrl+Appskey+'R')  
AppsKey & r::  
if not GetKeyState("Control")
; Neither the left nor right Control key is down.  
    return  ; i.e. Do nothing.  
msgbox, hello... ctrl appskey r  
return
```

Or you can do this...

```
AppsKey & Ctrl::    ; AppsKey, then Ctrl  
^AppsKey::          ; Ctrl, then AppsKey  
    Hotkey, *r, ^@r, On  
   ; additional hotkeys can be enabled here.  
return  
AppsKey & Ctrl Up:: ; Modifier(s) released   
^AppsKey Up::  
    Hotkey, *r, Off  
    ; additional hotkeys must be disabled here.  
return  
^@r:    ; Label for identification only, can be anything.  
    msgbox, hello... %A_ThisLabel%  
return
```

Comment: @avrik, To format an **inline** sample of code, surround the text with backticks, e.g. \`CODE\`. To format a **block** of code, indent each line of text with 4 spaces, or use the **Code Sample** button on the Editor Toolbar. :)

Comment: @iglvzx thanks for the edit. I will keep that in mind next time.