# How do I create a hotkey for a sequence of inputs while holding Ctrl, e.g. {Ctrl Down}ec{Ctrl Up}?

Tags: autohotkey

For example, in Visual Studio Express 2013, many of the formatting shortcuts have been "folded" into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. To comment a selection, one would hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, hit <kbd>E</kbd>, hit <kbd>C</kbd>, *then* release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

[image]

If I were *sending* such input, I'd write

```
SendInput {Ctrl Down}ec{Ctrl Up}
```

But how do I make that sequence into a hotkey? I tried

```
{Ctrl Down}EC{Ctrl Up}::
    MsgBox, "Hello, world!"
    Return
```

but of course, this causes a syntax error:

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question isn't specific to Visual Studio and you generally want to create a hotkey that uses more than one non-modifier key. The syntax of your hotkey declaration is way off, that's why I recommend reading [the respective part of the docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm). To your problem: Combining more than one non-modifier keys in a hotkey isn't provided for in standard AHK, but there's a workaround that simulates this behavior pretty well, check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20599074/1282023).

Comment: @MCL, thanks for the link! The loop solution indeed worked! But, I was determined to find a non-loop solution, and eventually found one (self-answered, below). Thank you for your thoughtful response, too. Actually, the `{Ctrl Down}EC{Ctrl Up}` wasn't a solution I tried in seriousness. I tried many other things (you can see some examples in my explanation), but I didn't want to explain _everything_ I tried, and I also didn't want to scare off users who might help me, by looking like I already tried advanced techniques. I hope it's understandable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

### tl;dr

Replace `^e` with first desired keystroke. Replace `3` with ASCII index of second desired keystroke. This enforces that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is held through both keystrokes, else cancels.

```
~$Ctrl UP::
    ChordIsBroken := True
    Return
^e::
    ChordIsBroken := False
    Input, OutputVar, L1 M
    If (!ChordIsBroken && Asc(OutputVar) = 3)
    {
        MsgBox "Hello, World!"
    }
    Else
    {
        SendInput %OutputVar%
    }
    Return
```

<sup>To adapt this to <kbd>Shift</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, you'd have to replace the `Ctrl`s, remove the `M`, and do a simpler comparison like `OutputVar = C` instead of the `Asc(OutputVar) = 3`. Not sure how to extend this to `Alt` and `Win` but you might have to try `L2` or something of the sort.</sup>

### Explanation

[`Input`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm) seemed like an obvious place to begin. `Input` asks AHK to wait for user input, *e.g.*

```
^e::
    Input, OutputVar, L1        ; "L1" means wait for 1 keystroke then continue.
    If (OutputVar = "c")
    {
        MsgBox, "Hello, World!"
    }
    Return
```

The message box above triggers on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd>. But we're looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, so let's fix this:

```
^e::
    Input, OutputVar, L1 M      ; "M" allows storage of modified keystrokes (^c).
    If (Asc(OutputVar) = 3)     ; ASCII character 3 is ^c.
    {
        MsgBox "Hello, World!"
    }
    Return
```

Now we've got a message box on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. But there's a problem with this: the message box triggers even when I *release* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> between the two keystrokes. So, how do we detect essentially a `{Ctrl Up}` mid-input? You can't merely check on entrance—

```
^e::
    if (!GetKeyState("Ctrl"))
    {
        Return
    }
    Input, OutputVar, L1 M 
    ; ...
```

—nor can you merely check after input—

```
^e::
    Input, OutputVar, L1 M 
    if (!GetKeyState("Ctrl"))
    {
        Return
    }
    ; ...
```

—nor can you even get away with doing both, because no matter what, you'll miss the `{Ctrl Up}` while blocking for input.

Then I looked into [documentation on `Hotkey`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for inspiration. The custom combination operator, `&`, seemed promising. But unfortunately,

```
^e & ^c::
    ; ...
```

caused a compilation error; apparently the `&` is for combining *unmodified* keystrokes, only.

Finally, it was up to `UP`, and that's where I finally made the breakthrough. I redefined <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>'s `UP` to set a *toggle* that would prevent the message box from triggering!

```
$Ctrl::Send {Ctrl Down}     ; The $ prevents an infinite loop. Although this
$Ctrl UP::                  ; line seems redundant, it is in fact necessary.
    ChordIsBroken := True   ; Without it, Ctrl becomes effectively disabled.
    Send {Ctrl Up}
    Return
^e::
    ChordIsBroken := False
    Input, OutputVar, L1 M
    If (!ChordIsBroken && Asc(OutputVar) = 3)
    {
        MsgBox "Hello, World!"
    }
    Return
```

Now, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, then release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, nothing happens, as expected!

There was one last thing to fix. On "cancellation" (a "broken chord"), I wanted all keystrokes to return to normal. But in the code above, the `Input` would have to "eat" a keystroke before returning, regardless a broken chord or an irrelevant secondary keystroke. Adding an `Else` case nicely resolves this:

```
    Else
    {
        SendInput %OutputVar%
    }
```

So, there you have it—"chords" in AutoHotkey. (Although, I wouldn't exactly call this a "chord." More like a *melody*, with a bass line ;-)

---

@hippibruder generously points out that I can avoid defining `$Ctrl::` by using `~` to make `$Ctrl UP::` non-blocking. This allows some simplification! (See tl;dr section at top for final result.)

---

One more thing. If, perchance, upon "cancellation" (a "broken chord"), you'd like to issue the first keystroke, *i.e.* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> on its own, simply add that in the `Else` block,

```
    Else
    {
        SendInput ^e
        SendInput %OutputVar%
    }
```

and don't forget to change the hotkey to

```
$^e::
```

to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: Do you mind posting an example or linking to an example for `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `a` or some specific key?  I don't really understand your logic in the post.  Thanks!

Comment: This is for the case where one would like to assign an action to, for example, `Ctrl`+`k` followed by `Ctrl`+`a` _without releasing the `Ctrl`_. For something like `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`a` of course the proper method would be simply `^+a::`.

Comment: Wow fast response.  Well I'm trying to do the following with no luck `AppsKey::`, `Ctrl & AppsKey::` and `^+AppsKey::`.  The 1st and 2nd  works but not the 3rd

Comment: I think it's because `AppsKey` isn't technically a modifier key. Take a look at [Is it possible to use AppsKey or other keys as modifier](http://superuser.com/questions/431308/is-it-possible-to-use-appskey-or-other-keys-as-modifier) if you haven't already. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is build-in support for key chords in AHK.
One way to detect these would be to register a hotkey for the first key in the chord (^e) and then use the Input-Command to detect the next keys.

```
; Tested with AHK_L U64 v1.1.14.03 (and Visual Studio 2010)
; This doesn't block the input. To block it remove '~' from the hotkey and 'V' from Input-Cmd
~^e::
  ; Input-Cmd will capture the next keyinput as its printable representation. 
  ; (i.e. 'Shift-a' produces 'A'. 'a' produces 'a'. 'Ctrl-k' produces nothing printable. This can be changed with 'M' option. Maybe better approch; See help) 
  ; Only the next, because of 'L1'. (Quick-Fail; Not necessary)
  ; To detect 'c' and 'u' with control pressed I used them as EndKeys.
  ; If a EndKey is pressed the Input-Cmd will end and save the EndKey in 'ErrorLevel'.
  Input, _notInUse, V L1 T3, cu

  ; Return if Input-Cmd was not terminated by an EndKey
  ; or 'Control' is no longer pressed. (It would be better if Input-Cmd would be also terminated by a {Ctrl Up}. I don't know if that is possible)
  if ( InStr(ErrorLevel, "Endkey:") != 1
    || !GetKeyState("Control") )
    {
    return
    }

  ; Extract the EndKey-Name from 'ErrorLevel' (ErrorLevel == "Endkey:c")
  key := SubStr(ErrorLevel, 8)    
  if ( InStr(key, "c") == 1 )
    {
    TrayTip,, ^ec
    }
  else if ( InStr(key, "u") == 1 )
    {
    TrayTip,, ^eu
    }
  else
    {
    MsgBox, wut? key="%key%"
    }
return
```

Comment: Hi, @hippibruder. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it behaved strangely on my AHK (and I'm running AHK_L, too), and I couldn't figure out why. If you could explain your code a little bit (the `_`, the `ErrorLevel`, etc.) I'd be willing to try again and see if you indeed have the superior solution that I should accept.

Comment: @acheong87 I've added comments. Regarding your answer (can't add comment there): To get rid of "$Ctrl::Send {Ctrl Down}" add a '~' to "$Ctrl UP::" and remove "Send {Ctrl Up}". Also your code works perfect (i.e. like in VS) for me without the 'ChordIsBroken' variable all together (Only "^e" hotkey).

Comment: Cool, you're absolutely right about the `~`! Thanks. I do need the `ChordIsBroken` though because otherwise I can release `Ctrl` between the two keystrokes, which I don't want to allow. I'm baffled by why your solution isn't working for me. I guess I'm running AHK_L v1.1.09.00 so maybe I should update? But for me currently, with your script, hitting `Ctrl+E` causes a line (in a text editor) to be deleted.

Comment: I'm +1'ing you anyway because you definitely know what you're talking about, and helped me out with your comment. I'll upgrade my AHK later and report back if anything's changed.

Comment: My code doesn't block the keystrokes. Maybe your editor deletes the current line with `Ctrl+E`.
I just now realised that you don't want to allow a `{Ctrl Up}` at all. Mine imitates VS behaviour. (`{Ctrl Down}e{Ctrl Up}{Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}` is legit)